# Why didn't I receive the association bonus for Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, bug, reputation, association-bonus

I read [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/295628/i-didnt-get-the-association-bonus-at-stack-overflow) who seems to have a problem similar to mine, but the answer just points to the fact that the problem didn't exist in the first place.

It seems to me that, in my case, the problem exists indeed. On all Stack Exchange sites I can go to my reputation tab and see the "+100" Association bonus, except for Stack Overflow. When I noticed this, I thought that maybe Stack Overflow just didn't have an association bonus like the other sites, but it seems it should have it. Is it just me? How can I solve this?

P.S. maybe this is more suitable for [Meta SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com), I don't know. I posted it here since this is the only site for which I seem to have this issue.

Comment: Compared to your other Stack Exchange accounts/profiles, your Stack Overflow profile is relatively new. Maybe at some point you had a Stack Overflow profile, got the association bonus there, [deleted it](https://stackoverflow.com/users/delete/current), and then recreated it? According to [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/164226/398364), you can only gain the bonus once per site.

Comment: @Ivar it is pretty new, but I also have some that are newer. I do not think that I ever had another Stack Overflow, but even if I did, the "delete your account" page is very clear that even if you recreate an account, there will be no link whatsoever with your old one.

Comment: "I also have some that are newer" is not very relevant to the gist of Ivar's comment. And the copy on the "delete page" merely says that the content on the old account would be anonymized, and the new account won't be able to reclaim it. It does not say that the new account "won't be linked in any way" to the old account. New accounts are, for example, linked to old accounts for abuse detection purposes. So it could be that this is a similar instance. Maybe a mod can confirm if you ever had another, deleted account, or if this is indeed a bug.

Comment: @yivi that's true, I misunderstood Ivar's comment. Anyway, if an account is linked to the old one, it's effectively the same account, right? With the same reputation and all (and with the association bonus, if it had it before). However, how can I confirm what you're asking?

Comment: @Ivar That's not correct. If you delete your SO account and recreate it, you'll get the association bonus again if you had it before. I've seen this happen on other sites many times. (Of course, abusing this is a quick way to be stuck at 1 rep with a suspension.) OP is experiencing a rare bug where the association bonus just doesn't show up when it should.

Comment: No, if there was an old account and _if_ was deleted, it is **not** the same account. It would simply be a new account, but it _might_ get linked to the old account for the purposes of the association bonus. Again, we are speculating here. A mod would need to confirm if you had a previously deleted account (or not). If they can see that. And in any case, reading now Laurel's comment, all this speculation seems to be moot. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't seem like there's anything the community can do to help you here. What you really need to do is raise a [Contact Us](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/contact) request to get staff to look into and fix this for you.

Comment: I did, both on SO and MetaSO. I'll let you know if they ever reply.

Comment: Update: I did not receive any reply to my contact request, not even an email acknowledging my situation. Do you have any other solution to propose?

Comment: Patience. Sometimes it takes weeks I believe.